# How to get the coordinates of the bounding box in YOLO_NAS object detection?

Tags: yolo, nas

I recently installed supergradients to use YOLO_NAS, the example is very easy to make predictions, does anyone know how to get the bounding boxes of the objects? or the model’s predictions like another models yolo.

Example:

```py
from super_gradients.training import models

yolo_nas_l = models.get("yolo_nas_l", pretrained_weights="coco")

url = "https://previews.123rf.com/images/freeograph/freeograph2011/freeograph201100150/158301822-group-of-friends-gathering-around-table-at-home.jpg"

yolo_nas_l.predict(url, conf=0.25).show()
```

RESULT: an image drawn with the predictions

thanks

I was expecting the model to give me the predictions in an array with their bounding boxes and classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get predicted bounding boxes and classes in YOLO-NAS like this:

```
predictions = model.predict(url, conf=0.25)
prediction_objects = list(predictions._images_prediction_lst)[0]
bboxes = prediction_objects.prediction.bboxes_xyxy

int_labels = prediction_objects.prediction.labels.astype(int)
class_names = prediction_objects.class_names
pred_classes = [class_names[i] for i in int_labels]
```

The `predictions` object provides a generator when you call `predictions._images_prediction_lst`. With this approach, the actual detection doesn't take place until you call `list()` on the generator which then provides a list of "prediction/detection related objects". One of these objects is the 'prediction'. We can use this to get an array of predicted bounding boxes. Likewise we can also obtain a list of corresponding class labels.

This may not be explicitly in the [documentation](https://docs.deci.ai/super-gradients/documentation/source/welcome.html), (I couldn't find it). Instead, I would encourage you to explore with the [dir()](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_dir.asp) function to find out more about the outputs. e.g. see what this returns `dir(prediction_objects)`.

There are also more ways to perform inference using super-gradients, see this [notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1V28VsW1_iDkQJjJguBqS9rx_b3f0Bjnt?usp=sharing). For other examples see [this](https://deci-ai.github.io/super-gradients/welcome.html#getting-started)